# Ruby/Rails return with result if function call is returning something

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Please forgive me if this is something beginner level. I'm looking for a cleaner way of doing something like this,

```rb
def function
  return Books.all if Books.any?
  
  return BooksForeign.all if BooksForeign.any?

  nil
end
```

Since I'm basically duplicating the call, I was wondering if there's a simple and better way of doing this. I just want to return if there's anything returning with `Books` method or `BooksForeign` method as the method which expects a return doesn't care if it's Foreign Books or Not.

Comment: What do you want to return in case there are no records? `Books.all` would return a blank array if there are no records.

Comment: I actually want to continue the return chain. I should've been more clear. Will update the original post

Answer (score 3):

```
def function
  Books.all.presence || BooksForeign.all.presence
end
```

`Object#presence` is one of ActiveSupport's more useful core extensions to Ruby. It returns the object if its `present?` or nil otherwise. Empty collections are not `present?`.

If you had a whole list of classes you could use [Enumerable#find](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-find) which would return the first non-falsy value:

```
[Foo, Bar, Baz].find { |klass| klass.all.presence }
```

Comment: It should be noted that `Books.any?` creates a separate query to check if there are any records. `Books.all.presence` will just load the collection and `.presence` will coerce it into an array. If you really want two queries you would do `[Foo, Bar, Baz].find { |klass| klass.any? }&.all`. Don't know why you would though.